# Returning a pointer to structure from a function

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have been trying to return a pointer to a structure from a function using the following code and a function which accepts a structure and returns a pointer to it :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct mystruct
{
    int id;
    char name[10];
};


//this is the function
struct mystruct *return_pointer(struct mystruct a)
{
    struct mystruct *ptr;
    ptr = &a;
    return ptr;
}

int main()
{
    struct mystruct tag, *p;
    tag.id = 12;
    strcpy(tag.name,"abcd");

    printf("Values are: %d\t%s",tag.id,tag.name);
    p=return_pointer(tag);

    printf("\nValues through pointer: %d\t%s", p->id, p->name);
    return 0;
}
```

but when i try to access the structure's values using the returned pointer, its not working properly. It is only displaying the 'id' but not the 'name'.
What can be the possible problem here?
I have read in a book which said to use this in function's body:

```
ptr = (struct mystruct *)malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
ptr-> id = a.id; 
strcpy(p->name,a.name); 
//struct 'a' is argument to function

return ptr;
```

If this is the correct solution then why so?

Comment: What's the purpose of the `return_pointer` function ? It's seems pretty pointless.

Comment: @MichaelWalz don't go on purpose!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you are returning the `a` that is a copy from the one you passed. Parameters in [c](/questions/tagged/c) are passed by value, thus `a` is a copy of `tag` allocated in a different place, that place is the stack frame of the function and it is destroyed when the function returns.

So at the moment of printing you are printing the deallocated `struct`, and that is undefined behavior. If you want your code to work for whatever reason try this

```
struct mystruct *
return_pointer(struct mystruct *a)
{
    return a;
}
```

and in `main()` change it to

```
p = return_pointer(&tag);
//                 ^ Pass the address of tag and return it
//                   the same as
//                    
//                                   p = &tag;
//
//                   which is why they say it's pointless in
//                   the comments
```

When you use `malloc()` you allocate the `struct` on the heap, the data will be valid wherever accessible<sup>1</sup> until you manually destroy it with `free()`, the `free()` function will simply release the memory it doesn't care what will be done with it later, it just gives it back to where it came from.

Also, ALWAYS check the return value of `malloc()`.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Wherever there is a pointer holding the address of the memory originaly returned by `malloc()`. This is exactly the address that you MUST pass to `free()` when you decide that you don't need the `struct` anymore.</sub>

Comment: But really, just `p = &tag;` would do just fine.

Comment: @Caleb, I know see the final answer please.

Comment: Sorry, missed your comment, but maybe if we all say it 10 or 12 times the message will get through. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

You should do this instead:

```
p = &tag;
```

To point to the same structure `tag`. Don't do this:

```
p = return_pointer(tag);
```

Because when you pass the `tag`, you pass it by value and it creates a copy (which is called `a` in the function `return_pointer`) thus, your `tag` and `a` (specifically, the addresses of those (that is `&tag` and `&a`) are different - See Mr. Caleb's comment) in the function is not the same.

Comment: Specifically, `&tag` and `&a` will have different values.

Comment: @Caleb ah yes, you are right. That is more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Function parameters are the function's local variables. They are destroyed after the function finishes its work.

What you are trying to do is to pass a structure by reference and return the reference to it. In this case the function will look like

```
//this is the function
struct mystruct * return_pointer( struct mystruct *ptr )
{
    return ptr;
}
```

and called like

```
p = return_pointer( &tag );
```

Though there is no great usefulness of such a function. Nevertheless in general it could for example change some data members of the passed object.

Comment: _no great usefulness of such a function_...  I can think of a few, including an application calling into a library that services several subscriptions to a _[PSP](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4554519&url=http%3A%2F%2Fieeexplore.ieee.org%2Fxpls%2Fabs_all.jsp%3Farnumber%3D4554519)_ network where a simple call into the library can pass information to library, and update application via a `struct *`.  Nevertheless, good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am a code-beginner from china,the error of your code is that the domain of local variable （ptr which is a pointer） is only effective in the function，but when your return it to your global main function，the memory which it point to have been freed. so it turn into a error. MY PLEASURE TO ANSWER YOUR !